# How can I create a .jks file using a Certificate from a smart Card?

Tags: java, x509certificate, jks

I am using Aladdin etoken and am able to read the certificate from it.
Now I have to create a .jks with the Certificate.
How do I export the Certificate from the smart card and create a .jks file?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this following code. Here, I am creating a keystore for JKS and make entry for my certificate under a preferable alias. Finally write the file (example: demo.jks)

```
X509Certificate x509Certificate = Util.getX509Cert(x509FileLocation); 
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
store.load(null, null);
store.setCertificateEntry("alias", x509Certificate);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(jksFileLocation);
store.store(fileOutputStream, "123456".toCharArray());
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thanks.. In the first line you have added the fileLocation.. Can you tell me which file you are talking about?

Comment: Right now, I do not have a smart card. So, I am reading a .cer/.crt file from HDD. If you are reading the certificate data from your smart card, then convert the byte array to X509Certificate object. then set the certificate entry. To convert the byte array to X509Certificate object use CertificateFactory class. Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html

Comment: Please let me know if there any help I can do.

Comment: Can you please tell me the Util comes from which class?

Comment: It was my own class. I created a class to get the X509Certificate. You already got the certificate, right? so the first line is nothing related to your question.